# Can't get endAt on videos when calling

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2Csnippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLFs4vir_WsTwwb2zqmtE2WTEFdc7AQHnc&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

This returns all data, but only videoId in each video contentDetails. Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: Why the down vote? This question is perfectly valid. The documentation shows duration should be returned. But in practice this is not the case!

Comment: I too don't understand why the down vote, and your question has helped me and saved me some trouble. up voted.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has removed the features that set start and end times to playlist items: here's a product forum post that details this (and indicates an official response from Google account reps):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/Gipu_cCDScI

Since playlists can no longer set start/end times on its items, the API no longer delivers them.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems (end of page) - "contentDetails.endAt string
The time, measured in seconds from the start of the video, when the video should stop playing. (The playlist owner can specify the times when the video should start and stop playing when the video is played in the context of the playlist.) By default, assume that the video.endTime is the end of the video."

Comment: I filled a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7320&thanks=7320&ts=1434633804

Comment: The API should be returning the 'note' in the contentDetails, as that's still part of the object, but the startAt and endAt attributes don't exist anymore, so really what needs to happen is that the documentation is updated to remove reference to them.

Comment: Arg, you might be right indeed. It's really annoying because it limits possibilities a lot... I was using it to trigger timed javascript events when reaching the end of a video. It was really cool, I can't believe they remove this from one version of the API to another! Ok, I'm going to add this to the bug report, hopefully they will re-add it soon!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a workaround. You can retrieve a playlist and use videos list with up to 50 videoIds in the URL to retrieve each video duration.